# Missing columns in look-up column

Tags: 2013, list, office-365, lookup-column, column

I created a new document list and enabled some column in the view:

[image]

Afterwards a I created a custom list and added a look up column. In this column I would like to specify a column of my document list, e.g. Name.
As you can see I only have some of the columns, Name is not one of them:

[image]

Comment: You should set the Title field in your document library to required, and then use that field in your lookup.

Comment: @user19952: I would like to use the field "Name" as a look-up field. How can I set it to required?

Answer (score 2):

Not every field you create in a list can be used in lookup columns, Name appears to be one of them, but you also won't see things like Multiple Lines of Text fields.

> SharePoint can only perform a lookup of values from columns that
>   contain a ‘text’ value, and then only if it contains a single line of
>   normal text (ie. “Single line of text”, a “number”, or “date”). Any
>   field that contains multiple lines of text, other lookups, or
>   multi-select items won’t be available to you, as SharePoint will
>   automatically hide any columns that it knows it can’t return.

http://blog.kiwibees.net/?p=85